# Is there any way I can count the number of pages of a word document in python?

Tags: python, python-docx

I am asked to count the number of pages of a word document without converting it to a pdf type.

I tried 'counting the sections' method to count the number of pages, but that method proved to be inaccurate, I need to accurately count the number of pages of word document using `python-docx`
library.

Update -
Since the documents wouldn't have anything unique to it, counting the pages using a place holder is not possible, the only unique thing to each page will be its page number as its footer.

Comment: is there any format of word document that start the pages with some specific heading or any unique thing that we can refer?

Comment: It cant be done accurately, only a rough estimate can be extracted

Comment: Would you be willing to use the win32 api to get it?

Comment: @Tanveer the only thing we can refer from the word document is the page no. as a footer on the bottom right corner.

Comment: yes i count it how many number of pages in single docx file. There are other approaches as well i'll add it in the answer, if it seem  ican do it like how i do, you can use my answer.

Comment: @VedantBhatt Can you give an example of how one of the documents look like?

Comment: @Cow well the document is a sort of KPI of certain deliverables, and each page consists of a different KPI and to count the overall RFT deliverable performance I need to calculate the total number of pages in the document. It is a bit confidential and hence I won't be able to share the file :/ hope u understand.

Comment: @VedantBhatt I'm not asking you to share confidential information. Make 3 pages with random text, that has the same page number footer, like you wrote, so that it would be easier to make a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `python-docx library`. You can install it like this:

```
pip install python-docx
```

Here is the code:

```
from docx import Document


def count_pages(doc):
    page_count = 0
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
                 # Microsoft Word 2010 - Level 2 is an text find at the end of the page.
                 # so on the base of it, i count total number of pages. 
        if para.text == 'Microsoft Word 2010 - Level 2':
            page_count += 1
    return page_count


doc_path = 'test.docx'
doc = Document(doc_path)
num_pages = count_pages(doc)

print(f'This document has {num_pages} pages.')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but sadly I won't be able to add text at the end of each page. The way you have added 'Microsoft Word 2010 - Level 2' isn't practically feasible for my requirements.

Comment: You are welcome. The word `Microsoft Word 2010 - Level 2` is already written in document, I just get and count the number of pages as your question title tells